# Windows firewall configuration for Weblogic server

Tags: port, weblogic, firewall, blocked

I've got a Weblogic server environment setup that all works fine on my server - I've set up a Windows firewall inbound rule to expose ports 7001 & 7002, but all attempts to access the server (e.g. using curl commands) are still blocked by the firewall. When the firewall is disabled, everything (curl, Webserver console etc) works fine, so it looks like something else in my firewall that I need to configure but I can't figure out what else I need to do, any pointers? (Wireshark confirms correct ports are being specified in my calls)

Comment: Did you allow http/https protocols at the firewell level ?

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel - in the "Protocols and Ports" section of firewall, I created as "Protocol type" = TCP - is that what you meant??

Comment: You may need to enable HTTP/HTTPS application protocols in the firewall.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specific "Protocol type" of HTTP/HTTPS available to choose from, the closest choice seems to be TCP

Comment: (Database connections using port 1521 are working fine with firewall enabled)

Answer (score 0):

There was a 'block' firewall rule on the Java exe - disabling this higher priority 'block' rule has sorted it by allowing the 7001/7002 'permit' rule to kick in.